# How to share a C struct among C S-functions?

Tags: c, simulink

Is there a way to share a C structure (instantiated only once) among several C S-functions? Here's what I mean: I have a Simulink model with many blocks that are implemented as C S-functions. There are many model parameters that are needed in those blocks and I would like to create a single object that holds all model parameters and is instantiated only once when I start the simulation. Right now I instantiate this object for each S-function in order to access the parameters but it would be nice to share this object among the S-functions.

Just a pure guess: Could I place my model parameters structure in a separate DLL and access it afterwards from each C S-function? Has any of you done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully implemented and tested the DLL idea (i.e. gather all model parameters in a struct inside a DLL - plus any necessary calculations - and link it to other C S-functions). Simulink is a single process and I believe the simulation is a single thread (if not there are ways to make it thread-safe).

The structure with model parameters from the DLL acts as a singleton (instantiated only once per simulation and shared among other S-functions).

**Update** (some replies from mathworks):

The simulation part from Simulink is always single threaded. Hence, there are no thread-safety concerns for the shared DLL.

The global variables for the different S-function blocks would share the same memory location.  This implies that a single instance of the shared library will be loaded for all of Simulink.  Therefore all S-function instances that load the shared library will be referring to the same shared library and data.

Alternatively you can also consider using the Data Store Blocks to implement global variables. This will require a signal connection from each S-function to the appropriate Data Store Blocks.  But a connection between S-functions would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could allocate and store the values in a separate DLL, although it seems complicated.  Sharing DLLs between s-functions a few years ago, I found Matlab/Simulink's DLL loading to be opaque and hard to manage (e.g. loading dependent DLLs).

A simpler approach - have one s-function allocate the structs in its DWork vector :

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/about-dwork-vectors.html

then store the pointer values to some workspace / global variables, where they can be accessed later on by the other s-functions.

Probably the easiest way to write to workspace / global variables using mexEvalString, and to read from them using mexGetVariable (Mathworks documentation is great for these and other functions)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. But first: do all S-functions from one Simulink model share the memory? Could I simply instantiate a struct in a block and pass its address as an input (or parameter) to the other blocks (also S-functions but different than the one holding the struct)?

Comment: yes I think they use the same memory space, the problem is finding a nice mechanism to pass addresses between them. Passing them as parameters will be difficult - Simulink expects the parameters for all s-functions to be set up before starting

Comment: writing to a workspace variable / reading from a workspace variable is one mechanism to pass the addresses.  I guess you could pass them as data inputs too...although they won't change over the length of the simulation, it seems a bit strange to pass the same value on every simulation tick

Comment: I would recommend using the DWork vector to store the structs - if you just allocate memory in a block, I'm not sure how Simulink will deal with / respect it.  The documentation recommends the DWork vector to store anything that you want to persist between successive calls to the model.