# Share data between multiple c mex s-functions

Tags: c, simulink, mex, s-function

I am implementing several c s-functions. They have to rely on the same pointers and variables, inedependet of the current s-function.

Basically I want to instantiate all variabels and pointers in one "setup" s-function (inside mdlInitialize) and then be able to use these variables an pointers in different s-functions in their mdlOutputs function. Every s-function will be written in c.

I could not find any usefull hint in the mathworks help. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways this can be done, although none of them are clearly the *best* approach.

One approach is to define everything in a dll and have that loaded by each of the S-Functions.  That is outlined in the question [How to share a C struct among C S-Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966799/how-to-share-a-c-struct-among-c-s-functions).

Another (and my preferred) approach is to create a custom data type, which is a C-struct containing all of the shared data, and have that passed as a signal between the S-Functions in the model.  This is outlined in the section `Using Opaque Data Types in C S-Functions` of the doc [Configure Custom Data Types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/custom-data-types.html).

The doc shows various (relatively simple) things that need to be done in the S-Function that creates a custom structure.  In this S-Functions `MdlOutputs` method, the custom struct would then just be made the output of the block in the usual way.  For example, if the custom struct containing your data is defined as,

```
typedef struct{
    real_T sig0;
    real_T sig1;
}myStruct;
```

Then in `mdlInitializeSizes` you need something like,

```
myStruct tmp;

/* Register the user-defined data types */
id = ssRegisterDataType(S, "customDataType");
if(id == INVALID_DTYPE_ID) return;

/* Set the size of the user-defined data type */
status = ssSetDataTypeSize(S, id, sizeof(tmp));
if(status == 0) return;

/* Set the zero representation */
tmp.sig0 = 0;
tmp.sig1 = 0;
status = ssSetDataTypeZero(S, id, &tmp);
```

And to output this as a signal, in the `mdlOutputs` method you'd have something like

```
myStruct *pY0 = (myStruct *)ssGetOutputPortSignal(S, 0);

pY0[0].sig0 = 'value of this param';
pY0[0].sig1 = 'value of this param';
```

Then in the `mdlInitializeSizes` of any S-Function that needs to use this signal you need

```
DTypeId  id;
id = ssRegisterDataType(S, "customDataType");
if(id == INVALID_DTYPE_ID) return;
```

which then gives you access to the custom struct within any of the other methods by using,

```
myStruct **uPtrs = (myStruct **) ssGetInputPortSignalPtrs(S,0);
```

The elements of the struct then get accessed in the usual way,

```
firstVar = uPtrs[0]->sig0;
secondVar = uPtrs[0]->sig1;
```

The primary drawback of this approach is that the model cannot be used in code generation (using Simulink Coder).

Comment: Thanks! But I will need code generation, because this has to run on external hardware. This is why I do all of this in c. Maybe I should have mentioned it in my initial question. Does the dll-approach work (in general) with code generation?

Comment: The dll approach should work, as long as you can compile the dll for the platform being used (and write the appropriate .tlc file(s)).

Comment: There is one thing I do not understand: if I declare the same variables in two different s-functions (outside of any mdl-function) I get an error about already defines variables. Okay. But if I do declare them only in one s-functions, I get an error that the variables are undefined in one s-function. How does this make sense? Do multiple s-functions share the same global memory for variables or not? Is there no way to globally define variables for c-s-functions beside the dll-approch or your workaround? This seems odd.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to share them across different S-Functions (that is, S-Functions with different functionality).  It is possible (and relatively easy) to share them across multiple instances of the same S-Function (but I assume this is not what you are asking for).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for sharing data between S-functions in the *generated code* would be just to pass it through global variables, in case your S-functions are non-inlined.

Because you get an error with already defined variables, I suppose you're compiling the generated code in a target platform. In this case, it is caused by the duplicate definitions -- global variables have to be defined only in "setup" S-function, and declared with *extern* keyword in all other S-functions (this is just a plain C in the target).

When S-function is compiled with mex in Simulink environment, it cannot be statically linked to other S-functions. While one can link multiple S-functions with the same external C source file, in the Simulink one will probably get multiple instances of the same data created independently for each S-funciton. Because S-function are compiled and linked independently in the Simulink environment, defining common global variables in each S-function doesn't make sense -- you cannot extern them as they wouldn't be defined for linker (invoked by mex).

The obvious drawback of linking globals on the target is that you can't use Simulink environment to debug functionality which depend on the shared data. But if it's not the main functionality (some supplemental logging for instance), it can be conditionally included with RT flag inside your S-functions to appear only in the generated code allowing to validate the main functionality in the Simulink.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. Even if a year is passed since I asked this question, I think this is still useful for many people. I did solve my problem back then by just using one s-function, but I might have a look at the “extern”-approach.